# How do I remove anybody from a dist list in Exchange for users without an email address?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, distribution-list

I am trying to migrate users from on prem exchange to the o365 but when running a script, I realized that if the dist list has users which doesn't have an email address, it would not run.

So before running this script, I would like to run a powershell script to remove any users from a dist list which has a blank PrimarySmtpAddress attribute.  If it is possible, I would like to create a file which export the names of people whose name were removed.  Thanks alot.

Fix an issue with migrating to o365.

Comment: It's been years since I last administered an Exchange server, but I thought that _every_ Exchange user _has_ to have an email address of some kind (e.g. IIRC, Exchange 2003 required everyone to have an X.400 address), that is: it's impossible to be in a DL without an e-mail address -

Comment: No, I'm still using exchange 2013 and it doesn't do that.  In any case, I figured out  a way to do it, on the script which I used to migrate users, i ended configuring the array to remove anybody which has a blank smtp address.